# Count active items/year without a temporary year table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, firebird

With the following record structure:

```
<item> | <start>    | <stop>
Item-A | 2013-04-05 | 2014-06-07
Item-B | 2012-06-07 | 2015-03-07
```

Is it possible to query using SQL (in MS-SQL >=2008 and Firebird >= 2.5) how many items are active per year? The result should be:

```
2012 | 1
2013 | 2
2014 | 2
2015 | 1
```

I've used a temorary table containing series (1900..2100) and join the origin table and temporary table using BETWEEN and extract(year..). But I'm searching for a better solution without using an extra table.

Comment: Use derived table/subquery/cte instead of real table

Comment: If you need a statement that works in both SQL Server and Firebird, then that is highly unlikely.  For instance, the functions to extract the year from a date are different in the two databases

Comment: Why not create a permanent single-column table with numbers 1 to some arbitrarily large number (say 1000) and use that to generate your series of years?

Comment: What is wrong with using a table of years? Having a permanent table of numbers is useful in many areas.

Answer (score 1):

This meets your requirement.

```
select Years.[Year],
       count(1) [Count]
from MyTable mt
join (select distinct(year(start)) as [Year] 
      from MyTable

      union 

      select distinct(year(stop)) 
      from MyTable

      union 

      select year(getdate())
      from MyTable 
      where exists 
          (select 1 
           from MyTable 
           where stop is null)) as Years
on Years.[Year] between Year(mt.start) and Year(isnull(mt.stop, getdate()))
group by Years.[Year]
order by Years.[Year]
```

Comment: The subselect 'Years' can't return years not included in any start/stop value, isn't it? For example, for a single row with start year 1980 and stop year 2014 the query only returns 1980 and 2014?

Comment: @ctrinox, you are right, but usually with real data I would be confident that this would never be the case. See my other answer if your data could have this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it using a helper function.

```
declare @StartMin datetime
declare @StopMax datetime

select @StartMin = min(start),
@StopMax = max(isnull(stop, getdate()))
from MyTable

select Years.[Year],
count(1) [Count]
from MyTable mt
join [dbo].[YearsBetween](@StartMin, @StopMax) as Years
on Years.[Year] between Year(mt.start) and Year(isnull(mt.stop, getdate()))
group by Years.[Year]
order by Years.[Year]
```

This is the helper function, I have a lot of them, DatesBetween, MonthsBetween, NumbersBetween, etc.

```
create function [dbo].[YearsBetween](@Start datetime, @Stop datetime)
returns @Years TABLE
(
[Year] int
)
begin
declare @StartYear int
declare @StopYear int

set @StartYear = year(@Start)
set @StopYear = year(@Stop)

while(@StartYear <= @StopYear)
begin
    insert into @Years 
    values(@StartYear)

    set @StartYear = @StartYear + 1
end

return;
end
```